# Find all transaction of same within time window before each observation in R

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, processing-efficiency

I have a data base of work orders containing materials reserved for different plants.
I need to find how many times each material have been requested in a time window before the current observation.

I have tried the following approach, but with a dataframe of 7 million lines, i'll take 300 months.

```
result<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(work.orders)){
  wo.date_f<- work.orders$original_basic_start_date[i] %>% as_date()
  days.back<-30 # Time windows for searching
  mat_f<- work.orders$material[i]
  plant_f<-work.orders$plant[i]
  total_resb_found<-work.orders %>% filter(plant==plant_f,
                       material==mat_f,
                       (original_basic_start_date %>% as_date())<wo.date_f,
                       (original_basic_start_date %>% as_date())-wo.date_f<days.back) %>% nrow()
  result[i,1]<-mat_f
  result[i,2]<-plant_f
  result[i,3]<-total_resb_found
  print(paste0(i," out of ", nrow(work.orders)))
}
```

So the approach is:

1. Find date, material and plant of row 1.
2. filter main data frame for material and plant found in previous step
3. filter data frame for dates before date found in step 1, and also after said date - time window
4. count how many lines found
5. record result in data frame

I understand this is a brute-force approach, so deffinitely tons of room for improvement, but i havent been able to think of a good one
Any ideas on a more efficient approach?

Thanks

Edit: added a sample data with desired result (as result column)

```
 structure(list(material = c("000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010199498", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010199498", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010199498", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010199498", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010199498", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010199498", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010199498", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010199498", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010199498", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010199498", "000000000010199498", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010199498", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010199498", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010199498", "000000000010199498", 
"000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", "000000000010339762", 
"000000000010339762"), original_basic_start_date = c("20201106", 
"20200702", "20200618", "20200923", "20201205", "20201118", "20201231", 
"20201022", "20200819", "20200823", "20201118", "20201106", "20201106", 
"20200826", "20201123", "20201111", "20200912", "20200930", "20200916", 
"20200717", "20200702", "20200929", "20201016", "20200624", "20201123", 
"20201105", "20200620", "20200626", "20200608", "20200712", "20200616", 
"20201209", "20200904", "20210130", "20201123", "20201117", "20200620", 
"20210311", "20200812", "20201130", "20200816", "20200802", "20200805", 
"20200705", "20200731", "20201123", "20200703", "20200926", "20200718", 
"20201105", "20200618", "20200815", "20200609", "20200729", "20210112", 
"20201121", "20210110", "20201008", "20200705", "20200902", "20200918", 
"20200713", "20200828", "20200722", "20210126", "20200906", "20200902", 
"20210106", "20201229", "20210117", "20210321", "20210204", "20201005", 
"20210109", "20210106", "20210526", "20210203", "20201001", "20201206", 
"20210221", "20210103", "20210112", "20200719", "20201019", "20200707", 
"20210110", "20210219", "20200710", "20210331", "20210103", "20201222", 
"20201027", "20210116", "20210130", "20200709", "20210120", "20210208", 
"20210220", "20201106", "20210205", "20201223", "20210211", "20210303", 
"20210428", "20200724", "20210203", "20200831", "20210207"), 
    plant = structure(c(16L, 34L, 16L, 16L, 21L, 20L, 10L, 15L, 
    25L, 37L, 20L, 37L, 37L, 10L, 17L, 25L, 32L, 39L, 25L, 16L, 
    37L, 17L, 19L, 25L, 27L, 16L, 39L, 34L, 17L, 19L, 17L, 25L, 
    16L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 36L, 17L, 16L, 27L, 16L, 37L, 16L, 16L, 
    17L, 16L, 39L, 32L, 19L, 27L, 19L, 16L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 15L, 
    39L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 25L, 16L, 16L, 19L, 25L, 
    19L, 27L, 17L, 33L, 32L, 33L, 15L, 25L, 25L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 
    16L, 20L, 16L, 16L, 37L, 16L, 16L, 37L, 25L, 27L, 37L, 32L, 
    37L, 37L, 19L, 21L, 20L, 17L, 27L, 47L, 16L, 16L, 25L, 25L, 
    16L, 32L, 16L, 20L), .Label = c("B201", "B21B", "B401", "B501", 
    "B504", "B521", "B701", "B71A", "B991", "C602", "C603", "C690", 
    "CS01", "CY01", "CY02", "CY04", "CY05", "CY06", "CY07", "CY08", 
    "CY09", "CY11", "CY12", "CY13", "CY16", "CY21", "CY30", "CY91", 
    "CY95", "D106", "D192", "FX01", "FX03", "FX05", "FX06", "FX07", 
    "FX10", "FX1A", "FX1C", "FX1E", "FX21", "FX5A", "FX5B", "FX5C", 
    "FX92", "FX94", "KB01", "PA02", "PA04", "PA05", "PA12", "PB1A", 
    "PB51", "PI01", "PI03", "PI08", "PI0A", "PI0B", "PI0F", "PN9A", 
    "PN9B", "PN9D", "PN9E", "PP9A", "PR90", "PR92", "PT01", "PT02", 
    "PT07", "PT08", "S501", "S502", "S503", "S504", "S505", "S507", 
    "S50I", "S516", "S517", "S593", "U201"), class = "factor"), 
    Result = c(23L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 
    5L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 22L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 15L, 5L, 25L, 24L, 0L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 
    11L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 25L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 4L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 20L, 2L, 14L, 17L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 30L, 16L, 5L, 
    6L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 11L, 7L, 19L, 7L, 2L, 28L, 
    2L, 6L, 21L, 1L, 29L, 32L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 
    1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 27L, 31L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 13L, 4L)), .Names = c("material", 
"original_basic_start_date", "plant", "Result"), row.names = c(NA, 
-108L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you list a small sample of the data.frame?

Comment: this seems pretty straight forward, but without sample data it becomes impossible to provide an accurate answer..

Comment: sorry, added the sample

Comment: Hi there. There is one flaw with your current code, the output only have `mat_f`, `plant_f` and total count of similar within range of 30 days. However you may ended up with multiple records have same `mat_f`, `plant_f` and different total count as they are from different date. How do you deal with this?

Comment: That is a very good point, i should probably add the original date. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I updated the approach which should consistently perform fast less than 1hrs for 7M records (unless your data is 7M records per day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues with your current approach that cause the increase in time is these line of code

```
result[i,1]<-mat_f
result[i,2]<-plant_f
result[i,3]<-total_resb_found
```

Adding one rows to matrix, dataframe in R is very inefficient and require a lot of additional work which would be fast when the number of rows is small. Once the number of rows reach certain threshold, the cost multiply by every new row. So you estimation of 300 months maybe a bit optimistics :)

*This is my personal experience testing various stuff. Though I haven't really quantify or do a thorough research on this. However I know for sure it related with memory allocation similar to performance issue when you pre-allocate memory for an array of 100 elements versus define an empty array and add one item at a time.*

#### Updated approach

After some stress test and further clearification here is my updated code for better performance

```
library(doParallel)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

# Parallel on 4 cores
registerDoParallel(4)

# Create a df which is 70000 your sample data (70000 x 108 = 7.5M records)
work.orders <- purrr::map_dfr(seq_len(70000), ~df)
# To allow more properly testing the data, a random date in span of one and a half years was generated and assign to original_basic_start_date
random_dates <- as.Date(rdunif(nrow(work.orders), as.integer(as.Date("2020-01-01")), as.integer(as.Date("2021-06-01"))), origin = "1970-01-01")
work.orders$original_basic_start_date <- random_dates
work.orders <- work.orders %>% arrange(original_basic_start_date)

# As the same material & plant on same date will return same results
# Therefore we only need to calculate once for those. Here is filter the 
# original data to only contain no duplicated date records for a pair of 
# material & plant
work.orders_unique_date <- work.orders %>% 
  group_by(material, plant) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(original_basic_start_date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(original_basic_start_date)
# Get all the date presented in the data
all_date_in_data <- unique(work.orders_unique_date[["original_basic_start_date"]])
# Time windows for searching
days.back <- 30 
# Time the performance
system.time(
  # Here for each date we filter the original data frame to only have date
  # that in the range of defined windows which allow faster calculation
  all_result <- bind_rows(foreach(i_date = all_date_in_data) %do% {
    message(sprintf("%s Process date: %s", Sys.time(), i_date))
    smaller_df <- work.orders %>% 
      filter(original_basic_start_date < i_date) %>%
      filter(original_basic_start_date - i_date < days.back)
    unique_item_on_date <- work.orders_unique_date %>%
      filter(original_basic_start_date == i_date)
    # for one date, calculate the requirement result for all pair of
    # material & plant on that date
    result <- bind_rows(foreach(i = 1:nrow(unique_item_on_date)) %dopar% {
      mat_f <- unique_item_on_date$material[i]
      plant_f <- unique_item_on_date$plant[i]
      # Here using the smaller df which already filter by date windows
      total_resb_found <- smaller_df %>%
        # Separate condition into multiple filter which should speed it up a bit
        filter(plant == plant_f, material == mat_f)
        nrow()
        tibble(date = i_date, mat_f, plant_f, total_resb_found)
    })
    result
  })
)
```

Some message output from the process above. Maximum 2 seconds per day consistently. If your data have 7M records in span of 2 years then it should take around 1 hour or even less

```
2021-03-12 08:58:41 Done Process date: 2020-08-15 in 1.83 seconds
2021-03-12 08:58:42 Done Process date: 2020-08-16 in 1.66 seconds
2021-03-12 08:58:44 Done Process date: 2020-08-17 in 1.93 seconds
2021-03-12 08:58:46 Done Process date: 2020-08-18 in 1.72 seconds
2021-03-12 08:58:48 Done Process date: 2020-08-19 in 1.77 seconds
2021-03-12 08:58:50 Done Process date: 2020-08-20 in 1.74 seconds
2021-03-12 08:58:51 Done Process date: 2020-08-21 in 1.78 seconds
2021-03-12 08:58:53 Done Process date: 2020-08-22 in 1.78 seconds
2021-03-12 08:58:55 Done Process date: 2020-08-23 in 1.73 seconds
2021-03-12 08:58:57 Done Process date: 2020-08-24 in 1.94 seconds
2021-03-12 08:58:59 Done Process date: 2020-08-25 in 1.78 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:00 Done Process date: 2020-08-26 in 1.78 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:02 Done Process date: 2020-08-27 in 1.81 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:04 Done Process date: 2020-08-28 in 1.84 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:06 Done Process date: 2020-08-29 in 1.83 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:08 Done Process date: 2020-08-30 in 1.76 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:10 Done Process date: 2020-08-31 in 1.94 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:11 Done Process date: 2020-09-01 in 1.78 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:13 Done Process date: 2020-09-02 in 1.86 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:15 Done Process date: 2020-09-03 in 1.82 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:17 Done Process date: 2020-09-04 in 1.80 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:19 Done Process date: 2020-09-05 in 1.88 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:20 Done Process date: 2020-09-06 in 1.78 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:23 Done Process date: 2020-09-07 in 2.08 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:24 Done Process date: 2020-09-08 in 1.89 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:26 Done Process date: 2020-09-09 in 1.88 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:28 Done Process date: 2020-09-10 in 1.86 seconds
2021-03-12 08:59:30 Done Process date: 2020-09-11 in 1.87 seconds
```

Timing of the first 100 days is 60 seconds

```
   user  system elapsed 
 93.281  73.571  60.310
```

And here is sample result

```
> tail(all_result, 20)
# A tibble: 20 x 4
   date       mat_f              plant_f total_resb_found
   <date>     <chr>              <fct>              <int>
 1 2020-04-08 000000000010199498 C602               13318
 2 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 FX01               66596
 3 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 CY04              441597
 4 2020-04-09 000000000010199498 CY16              160625
 5 2020-04-09 000000000010199498 FX03               13350
 6 2020-04-09 000000000010199498 FX10               13418
 7 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 CY07              120541
 8 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 CY30               80768
 9 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 FX10              120076
10 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 FX03               13498
11 2020-04-09 000000000010199498 C602               13448
12 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 FX1C               53672
13 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 CY08               80234
14 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 CY05              120682
15 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 CY09               40493
16 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 FX07               13325
17 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 CY02               40204
18 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 FX05               26671
19 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 C602               13576
20 2020-04-09 000000000010339762 KB01               13331
```

#### [Updated: add time to process whole 7.5M records]

```
    user   system  elapsed 
1665.785 1096.865  891.837
```

Comment: That is fantastic! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stab at it:

```r
plant.pool <- 1:4
material.pool <- 1:5
date.pool <- seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date(now()), by="day")
n.out <- 7e6

## Generate 7 mill records
d <- data.table(
    plant = sample( plant.pool, size=n.out, replace=TRUE ),
    material = sample( material.pool, size=n.out, replace=TRUE ),
    original_basic_start_date = sample( date.pool, size=n.out, replace=TRUE ),
    id = 1:n.out
)[ order(original_basic_start_date) ]

window.size <- 30

## Do the actual rolling calculation, and time it, demonstrating the first 100k only
system.time( the.counts <- frollapply(
    d[ 1:1e5, .(id) ],
    window.size,
    function(x){
        d[ id %in% x, sum( plant==last(plant) & material==last(material) ) ]
    }
))
```

As you can see, I deliberately process only the first 100k records, and time this.

After a couple of runs on my ageing workstation (8-9 years old, 8 cores),  it clocks in on around 17 seconds to process those 100k records. This might extrapolate to 3.3 hours, which is substantially faster than 300 months. Also your computer is likely faster than mine, so all the merrier. Once you see you have my speeds or faster, you could time the 100k rows as I do, and start it up and check back in when it should be done.

`data.table` is generally suited for big things that need to go faster. There might be better suited functions out there though (you might have to look to *python* or *c* even), though I haven't found a solution that could look at both material and plant column in their optimized rolling functions (`frollsum` w/friends)

**EDIT:**

You added data after my first attempt, but I think the principle of my approach still holds.

**EDIT 2:**

Also rollapply doesn't process the first 1:window.size rows, you would have to them yourself, (which should be a fairly simple matter now that you have 300 months minus a few hours on your hands)